# Display an alert in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript and I was following a tutorial where based on the code below, the button content was supposed to change to `adding` before displaying the alert but my code is not working

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form class="form-item">
    <div class="cart">
        <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" />
    </div>
</form>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            button_content.html('Adding...'); //Loading button text
            alert("Item added to Cart!"); //alert user
        });
    });
</script>
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: 1. Where is your `button` element in HTML? 2. What is `button_content`?

Comment: What is "button_content?"

Comment: You have not declared button_content anywhere in the code. You can change the html simply by doing : $(this).html("adding");

Comment: It is supposed to change the content of the button `add to cart` to `adding...` before displaying the alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this code a try for a few reasons.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form class="form-item">
    <div class="cart">
        <!--<input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" />-->

        <!-- First use a button not an input and give it an ID -->
        <button id="btn_add" type="submit">Add to Cart</button>
    </div>
</form>
<script>

    // You can shorten up the ready statement
    //$(document).ready(function(){

    $(function(){

        // Now bind a click handler with button's ID

        // This is an older way of binding in jQuery
        // $("#btn_add").click(function(){

        // Use jQuery's on() instead.
        $("#btn_add").on("click", function(){

            // Change the HTML of the button by getting it by it's new ID
            // button_content.html('Adding...'); //Loading button text

            $("#btn_add").html('Adding...');

            alert("Item added to Cart!"); //alert user
        });
    });
</script>
```

Use an ID anywhere that you can. Feel free to shorten up your ready statement. Use jQuery's [on handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of click.

Comment: thanks @pmahomme, working just like I want. How can I get in touch with you in case I need another help ?

Comment: @Prince you're welcome. Just ask again here on SO and I'm sure someone (maybe me) will help you out. ;)

Answer (score 2):

`$("button")` is not the right selector. That will look for `<button>` elements, and you don't have one.

You'll want `$("input[type=submit]")`, or better yet, give it an ID and use the selector on that: `$("#mybutton")`.

Keep in mind that this will still submit the form back to the server - it'll just wait until the alert to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a  tag to select it with jquery. Your html has to look like this for it to work:

```
<form class="form-item">
    <button class="cart">Add to Cart</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the jquery selector and in the function reference

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form class="form-item">
    <div class="cart">
        <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" />
    </div>
</form>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[type=submit]).click(function(){
            $(this).html('Adding...'); //Loading button text
            alert("Item added to Cart!"); //alert user
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button name="submit" value="Add to Cart" id="sendFeed">Add to card</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        button_content.html('Adding...'); //Loading button text
        alert("Item added to Cart!"); //alert user
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a `button` element in your code. If you are targeting the `input` element, then you need to use the `selector` tag for input and then use `.val()` option to display the text.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("input").click(function(){
            $(this).val('Adding...'); //Loading button text
            alert("Item added to Cart!"); //alert user
        });
    });
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/fz66qdv4/

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form class="form-item">
    <div class="cart">
        <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" />
    </div>
</form>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[type=submit]").click(function(){
            $(this).val('Adding...'); //Loading button text
            alert("Item added to Cart!"); //alert user
        });
    });
</script>
</body>     
</html>
```